# How to Pragmatically Check an Input Option in an Admin Form

Tags: magento2

I am fetching data and populating radioset options for an admin form.
I can populate the options but I want to have them checked based on the fetched data.
I tried putting 'checked' attribute but was not successful.
Can someone please guide me in the right direction?

```
<?php

namespace Hayward\SchedulePageBuilder\Ui\Component\Form;

use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;
use Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Speaker\CollectionFactory;

class Options implements OptionSourceInterface
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $options;
    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $collectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
    )
    {
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
        $items = $collection->getItems();

        uasort($items, function ($a, $b) {
            return strcmp($a['lastname'], $b['lastname']);
        });
        // I tried adding 'checked' => "checked" to the array below, but it didn't work.
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $formattedLabel = $item['lastname'] . ', ' . $item['firstname'];
            $this->options[] = ['label' => $formattedLabel, 'value' => $item['id'], 'checked' => "checked"];
        }
        return $this->options;
    }
}
```

form.xml

```
        <field name="speakers" formElement="radioset">
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Speakers</label>
                <dataScope>speakers</dataScope>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <radioset>
                    <settings>
                        <options class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Form\Options"/>
                        <multiple>true</multiple>
                    </settings>
                </radioset>
            </formElements>
        </field>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Do not Put "checked" inside toOptionArray()**, Just return the options array there.

**You need to use Correct the Data Provider for the Form**, Below I am attaching the reference, So that You can put into your code according to your need.

> ui_listing.xml file

```
<field name="speakers" formElement="radioset">
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Speakers</label>
                <dataScope>speakers</dataScope>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <radioset>
                    <settings>
                        <options class="Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Enabledisable"/>
                        <multiple>true</multiple>
                    </settings>
                </radioset>
            </formElements>
        </field>
```

> DataProvider.php file in (getData() function)

```
/**
     * Get data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        if (!$this->getCollection()->isLoaded()) {
            $this->getCollection()->load();
        }
        $items = $this->getCollection()->getData();
        if (isset($items[0])) {
            
            // Here is the main Code to checked the fields on the form
            $items[0]['speakers'] = json_decode($items[0]['speakers'], true);
            // Here is the main Code to checked the fields on the form
            
            $data[$items[0]['id']] = $items[0];
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

In the Above getData() function, you have seen that I have decoded the speakers field data, because I have saved the data in json format in database.

[image]

And then it will be checked according to data saved in db, So when you edit the existing form the options will be checked accordingly.

**Result (For reference) :**

[image]